# Why is it no longer possible to downvote Discussions posts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, discussions-space

Downvotes on Discussion posts seem to be either broken or deactivated.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78209740/can-i-increase-my-website-traffic-through-coding) is an example of what the UI currently looks like (the `"codding"` was supposed to be `"coding"`, and has nothing to do with ["playing jokes and tricks"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/codding), but this cannot be fixed, because the `Edit`/`Delete` functionality has been disabled as well).

[image: UI without the "Downvote" / "Edit" / "Delete" buttons]

Just wondering: Was this change intentional or is it a technical bug?

It seemed to work just fine a few days ago.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78210604/facturation-google-cloud-storage) really better not be some attempt to mirror what YouTube did with dislikes. I purposefully dislike content on YouTube because of that change. Every single discussion on the front page is by users with questions with more than 5 downvotes.

Comment: The relevant excerpt from the discussion linked in the "duplicate" explanation: _"we have removed the Discussions downvote function and removed downvotes from the Discussions post score calculation. The reasoning behind this change is that there is not (yet) a clear shared definition of what a downvote means in Discussions."_ So, _yes_, it seems to be intentional, and _no_, it does not seem to be a bug.